# Fix row in table when pressing the button more than once with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is the main page view:
[image: Main page view]

When I press the "Pilih Staff" button at first time, a modal will appear. And when I check it, it will run normally like this image:
[image: Modal view]

The results are still in line with expectations:
[image: List of table]

The problem occurred when I pressed the "Pilih Staff" button for the second time and so on. when I check another data, it will display duplicate data as much as I pressed the button. like this image:
[image: Duplicate data]

Here my html code:

```
<tbody id="myTable">
</tbody>
```

And here my Jquery code:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
        var nik = $(this).data("nik");
        var nama = $(this).data("nama");
        var rs = $(this).data("rs");
        var unit = $(this).data("unit");
        var jabatan = $(this).data("jabatan");

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>'+nik+'</td><td>'+nama+'</td><td>'+rs+'</td><td>'+unit+'</td><td>'+jabatan+'</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnDelete">Delete</button></td></tr>');
        } else {
            $('#myTable').closest('tr').remove();
            // $("#myTable input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest("tr").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you..

Comment: this is because you are appending the data. Replace the old data with new one...

Comment: `$('#myTable').html('...............')`;

Comment: when I check more than one, the old data will be overwritten by the new data. And only shows one data

Answer (score 0):

> This is because you are appending the data. Replace the old data with
>   the new one.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        $(this).each(function(){
            var nik = $(this).data("nik");
            var nama = $(this).data("nama");
            var rs = $(this).data("rs");
            var unit = $(this).data("unit");
            var jabatan = $(this).data("jabatan");

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#myTable').html('<tr><td>'+nik+'</td><td>'+nama+'</td><td>'+rs+'</td><td>'+unit+'</td><td>'+jabatan+'</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnDelete">Delete</button></td></tr>');
            } else {
                $('#myTable').closest('tr').remove();
                // $("#myTable input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Fenz have you checked the above answer?

Comment: when I check more than one, the old data will be overwritten by the new data. And only shows one data

Comment: So, what issue you have now.. explain in detail

Comment: the problem is exactly like the 4th image, when I click the "pilihstaff" button for the first time, modal will appear. And when I check the data and I close the modal, the data that appears in the table is correct. but when I click the "pilih staff" button for the second time, and I check the other data again, the data that appears in the table is double

Comment: So, are you saying if you check the checkbox once and then again check it, it gets again added in the table?

Comment: so for that, the most simple solution is that you have to keep which checkboxes are checked... When the checkbox is checked, add data in table and when checkbox is unchecked, remove it from table..

Comment: for now, when checkbox is unchecked, still can't remove it from table

Comment: And to anticipate when there is missing data, and when users want to add more staff data. and it will feel strange when the data that appears at once double

Comment: for now, when checkbox is unchecked, still can't remove it from table ....... share the code in question how you are removing the checked data.. or add a new question for same..